# vc++ 2010 add a function to a runtime RichTextBox or other control

Tags: function, c++-cli, runtime, controls

Firstly I’d like to thank you for taking the time to read this post.
Now down to business;

I’m used to using VB 2010 and would like to get back into c++ after a fairly length c++ hiatus, I am using vc++ 2010 and I can add a Button, Rich text box, etc and change its size and location at runtime using the flowing code:

```
RichTextBox^ MyRTBox = gcnew RichTextBox;
MyRTBox->Text = "RichTextBox Text Area.";
this->Controls->Add(MyRTBox);
MyRTBox->Height = 240;
MyRTBox->Width = this->Width - 100;
//Location can be set separately as bellow or it can be docked to the parent 
//fontrol/form
//MyRTBox->Location = Point(0,25);
strong textMyRTBox->Dock = DockStyle::Bottom;
```

Which works fine but I would like to add an event handler, such as on textchanged.
The reason I’m looking to do this it that I don’t know at design time how many RichTextBoxes will be needed and I want to be able to limit the amount of text that can be stored. 
I have seen methods to limit size but not in vc++ 2010 further to this I would eventually like to add an autocomplete feature based on words in string array.

Firstly, is this actually possible or should I be looking at creating a new class which includes a RichTextBox or inherits attributes of the RichTextBox System Class.

Comment: Based on the code above, it appears that you're using C++/CLI, not C++.

Comment: Just do this first with the Winforms designer.  Add a RTB to the form and implement its TextChanged event.  Which shows you exactly the kind of code you have to write yourself.